# Can I do parallel programming using my Intel HD 5000 GPU on MacBook Air OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, graphics, parallel-processing, gpu, intel

Is there a way to utilize Intel HD 5000 GPU for parallel programming? If so, where would one start? Are there any good tutorials out there? I was mainly thinking of trying out some highly parallelizable algorithms such as merge sort, closest points problem, convex hull variations and similar.

Comment: You can probably leverage this using OpenCL: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/accelerate-performance-using-opencl-with-intel-hd-graphics